# How to get rid of black spots in Choropleth map

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson, folium, choropleth

My Choropleth map has these weird black spots and i'm not sure if its missing data or not. How do I get rid of those black spots?

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Tlg.png)

My csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10FULaQ7f4lfWdPpk4bzwlD9yymGrL14d/view?usp=sharing

My GeoJson: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GZljNjbIXsx55xopN9_DDlOb0Pi9Eclz/view?usp=sharing

I'm running this on Jupyter:

```
    # CHOROPLETH MAP
import json
kunnat_geo = r'kuntarajat.geojson'
with open(kunnat_geo) as kunnat_file:
    kunnat_json = json.load(kunnat_file,encoding='utf8')
type(kunnat_json)

df = pd.read_csv('cleandata.csv')


map = folium.Map(location=[65,26], zoom_start=4, tiles='openstreetmap')
map.choropleth(geo_data=kunnat_geo,
             data=df, # my dataset
             columns=['Kunta', 'data'], 
             key_on='feature.properties.Name',
             fill_color='OrRd', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
             legend_name='Mielenterveyden kuntoutuskotien asiakkaat vuonna 2018',
             smooth_factor=0)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(map)
for i in range(0,len(coords)):

    folium.Marker([coords.iloc[i]['lat'], coords.iloc[i]['lng']], popup=coords.iloc[i]['data'],tooltip='Mielenterveyden kuntoutuskotien asiakkaat vuonna 2018').add_to(marker_cluster)
coords.head()

map.save('Choropleth.html')
map
```

Edit: Solved the issue. Folium isn't able to show nordic letters Ä, Ö or Å. Had to delete them from my data and now it works.

Comment: Here we are. What is `kunnat_geo`? It seems you do not use it in the code you posted. Moreover, running your code I do not get the result in the image you posted. May you check the correspondence between the code and the result you say to get? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code, but no results.

Comment: Let's check some regions. What are the names of the black regions at the top?

Comment: How do I check them? Because nothing pops up when I click the areas.

Comment: Any idea of the names?

Comment: I do have the names in my dataframe but I dont know where they locate.

Comment: Anyway, for those regions the name in the geojson file and in the csv file does not match.

Comment: I checked if the df and geojson names match and they do indeed match so I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized I was missing data in some of the cities. This happens because those cities have nordic characters in their name, and folium is not able to show them. Fixed it by replacing all nordic characters with english letters (Ä = A, Ö = O etc) with following code:

```
dictionary={'ä':'a','ö':'o','Ä':'A','å':'a'}
df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Also had to replace them manually in the geojson file.